# Delete a row of a tableview with data in array

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

How can I delete the row and its data in array?

I used ordered to save the items get from previous controller.

```
var ordered = [ItemList:Int]();

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        ordered.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)  
    }
}
```

It shows error message

> Cannot convert value of type "Int" to expected arguement type DictionaryIndex  ItemList, Int

on `ordered.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)`

Comment: `ordered` is a Dictionary that does not have the `removeAtIndex` function that expects an `Int` (see http://www.luby.info/2015/08/08/swift-dictionary-removeatindex.html). did you plan to use an array?

Comment: Consider that `ordered` is actually not ordered. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dictionary` provides `removeValueForKey()` compared to `removeAtIndex()` of `array`. So probably you must use the

```
ordered.removeValueForKey(yourKey)
```

where you must find the corresponding key using `indexPath.row` which requires an array to keep track of these keys or you just replace the `dictionary` with an `array`

Answer (score 0):

the `Dictionary` does have the `removeAtIndex` method, but You are passing it an Int, while it requires to be passed in a DictionaryIndex.

so first You need to get the key: `var indexKey = ordered.indexForKey(indexPath.row)`

assuming the key is an Int. 
then pass that to removeAtIndex:

ordered.removeAtIndex(indexKey)